# Can I just add vias underneath pads?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I have a lot of bypass capacitors on the back side of a PCB. I have been creating short traces to a via for connections to 3V1 and then the cap goes to GND. See diagram.  Can I, instead, just place these vias underneath the pad itself?

[image]

Comment: thank you, that does